# fish shell seems to be ignoring LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, fish

I need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for [CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions) prior to launching [darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/).  Looks like this:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

When the application launches, it fails to load a library it should have found in that directory:

```
./darknet 
./darknet: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.10.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But the library is definitely in that directory:

```
ldd /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.10.0
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe7bf2d000)
    ...etc...
```

I assume I'm not correctly setting up LD_LIBRARY_PATH in fish.  This is how I originally did it in fish:

```
set -U LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

**When I try the exact same thing in bash, it works fine**:

```
bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
./darknet 
usage: ./darknet <function>
```

All of this is on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.6 running fish 2.2.0 and bash 4.3.48.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You’re not exporting your variable. Instead, do:

```
set -Ux LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64
./darknet
```

Comment: Easy to miss that in the fish tutorials.  Thank you.

Comment: You really do not want to export universal vars. Doing so tends to cause more problems than it solves. Just `set -x` is all that's needed in your *config.fish*.

Comment: Sure. This could be set with `set -Gx LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64` just as easily. I’m using fish 3.0 and have not yet seen any problems with exported universal variables (but I don’t have many of them).